# Label with as: :boolean value in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have the following code :

```
  <%= profile.simple_fields_for :options,  OpenStruct.new(@user.profile.options) do |option| %>

    <div class="hint">
      <%= option.label :display_profile %>
      <%= option.input :display_profile,
                        as: :boolean,
                        label: false
                        %>
    </div>
```

But in my html code the label is in the input

[image]

If I remove as: :boolean in my form, the html is good (but It's not a boolean field)
[image]

How can I fix it ?

** EDIT **

I updated my code to :

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :profile do |profile| %>
  <%= profile.simple_fields_for :options,  OpenStruct.new(@user.profile.options) do |option| %>

    <div class="hint">
      <%= option.label :display_profile %>
      <%= option.input :display_profile,
                        as: :boolean,
                        boolean_style: :inline,
                        label: false
    </div>
```

But now I have two `<div>` How can I remove : `<div class="checkbox">` ?

```
   <div class="hint">
        <label class="string required" for="user_profile_attributes_options_display_profile">Afficher votre profil</label>
        <div class="field boolean optional user_profile_options_display_profile">
        <div class="checkbox">
           <input name="user[profile_attributes][options][display_profile]" type="hidden" value="0" />
           <input class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="user[profile_attributes][options][display_profile]" id="user_profile_attributes_options_display_profile" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Don't put the images of your code, put your code as text instead.

Comment: Check your simple_form initializer to see how it configures check boxes it is likely this is just a styling mechanism because in both cases your actual label is where it belongs it just seems that the wrapper for a boolean in your configuration puts the faux field inside a label tag

Comment: Seems to be [Here](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/inputs/boolean_input.rb#L8) and that is the default styling for simple_form checkboxes when `SimpleForm.boolean_style == :nested` [Here](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form.rb#L109)

Comment: I updated my question ;)